# How to import key that signs a repository for dnf/yum

Tags: yum, gpg, dnf

I've ran into this for dnf only, but I assume it's the same for yum. I can't find any explanations on how this is supposed to work.

One can set `repo_gpgcheck=1` in repository config file. So dnf is now supposed to check the signature of the repository data itself. I assume it still uses the `gpgkey` value from the repository config file.

How can I import that key into whatever key repository that dnf/yum are using to do the key check? I'm stuck with "Importing GPG key..." prompt every time the repository signature is validated, and there is no reason for me to not add a key as a trusted key. The keys imported by RPM do not work, I assume a different repository is checked for keys that can sign the repositories.

Answer (score 4):

Using

```
rpm --import <YOUR_PUBKEY_PATH_HERE>
```

[Source](https://getfedora.org/keys/faq/).

Comment: This is for packages, not repositories, my question is specifically about repositories. Keys imported with RPM have no effect when DNF/YUM check repository signatures.

Comment: For me? on CentOS 8 it work for dnf. So look like it share keys with rpm.

Comment: No, it doesn't always share keys with rpm. I have already done this: `rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi.el8` and yet when I do this: `dnf search php` I get prompted to import key `/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi.el8`

Comment: If you are behind a proxy you need to use the `--httpproxy` and `--httpport` variables. E.g. `sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc --httpproxy localhost --httpport 3128`. https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/man/rpm.8.html#ftphttp-options